# Disabling align=center on @media

Tags: css, media-queries

If I want to disable `align: center;` property only when the `@media` condition is satisfied what is the command I should use??

```
@media(max-width=750px){
    #innerh2{
        disable align;
    }
}
<div id="innerh2">
    <h2 align="center">CSS</h2>
</div>
```

---

```
@media(max-width=750px){
    #innerh2{
        align: none;
    }
}
<div id="innerh2">
    <h2 align="center">CSS</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute is deprecated and not supported in HTML5, as stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a better approach.
Remove the 'align' attribute from HTML, you do not need it at all.

Use class and not id selector for your div. Its not mandatory but try to leave *id* definitions for jQuery and similar uses. While allow reuse of your class.

You had wrong media query definition

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   .innerh2{
        text-align: center; /* or right, left, justify, initial etc... */
   }
}
<div id="innerh2" class="innerh2" ><h2>CSS</h2></div>
```

Comment: I'm just starting so I don't know about class or so...  :D  But thx for answering!!

Comment: @Luin If the answer worked for you please mark it as such. Thanks. If not, let us know

Comment: Don't know why but it's working as I wanted it to be :D

Comment: @Luin Please mark the answer as correct and head over to learn CSS :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `align` attribute was deprecated and is not supported in HTML5. You should use the CSS `text-align` property instead and center it when the width exceeds 750px.

```css
@media(min-width=750px) {
  .center-desktop {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="innerh2">
  <h2 class="center-desktop">CSS</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your following code

```
#innerh2{ 
align:none;
}
```

to css atribute `align` just add `text` like this :

```
#innerh2{
text-align:none;
}
```